# Python use in the same line "For", "If" and "Else"

Tags: python

I want to learn python "secrets", it's possible to put all this code in one line?:

```
word_not_clean="Casà: 25$"
word_clean=""
for x in word_not_clean:
    if x in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789':
        word_clean+=x
    else:
        word_clean+='_'
```

This sentences work, but no replace especial characters:

```
word_clean="".join(x for x in word_not_clean if x in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')
```

But this sentence with else doesn't works.

```
word_clean="".join(x for x in word_not_clean if x in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789' else '_')
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Let us know what went wrong in that last case. The full error text would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different kinds of `if` statements in generator expressions. The first kind (which I’ll call an “inclusion `if`”) comes *after* the `for` statement, and indicates whether a given item from an iterator should be included in the resultant list. This is what you’re using in the first example.

The second kind (which I’ll call a “ternary `if`”) comes *before* the `if` statement, and used Python’s ternary operator `__ if __ else __` to decide what should be outputted by the iterator. This is what you want for the second example, but you need to reorder your terms:

```py
OKAY = “abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789”
word_clean = "".join(
    x if x in OKAY else '_'  # Ternary if
    for x in word_not_clean
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try like the below and also, you can use `string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits`.

```
import string
word_not_clean="Casà: 25$"
chars_check = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits 


result = ''.join(x if x in chars_check else '_' for x in word_not_clean)

print(result)
# 'Cas___25_'
```

Explanation:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it using list comprehension (one-lining lines) add the if-else statement before the for:

```
chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
word_clean = "".join([x if x in chars else '_' for x in word_not_clean])
```